# How can I post a python game to my wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress, python-3.x

I'm learning to program using Python 3, and I've more or less finished my first project, a text adventure. I would like to post it to my wordpress website. I've looked for a python widget/plugin to no avail. Is this possibility at all?

Comment: So do you want to embed the game to a page? or do you just want people to download it to play offline on their own PCs

Comment: I'd rather embed the game, but downloading and playing offline is acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible.

Check with your host to see if it can handle python, then you need to config the web server (probably [apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) or [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html)) to serve the game on a specific section of your site (your.site/the-game).

It's probably best if you use ajax to run the game so you don't duplicate the layout of the site in python for that section.

Maybe it's easier to run the game on a sub domain (the-game.your.site), depending on your host conditions.